# Linear injection into $\mathbb{R}$ of a normed vector space

Tags: functional-analysis

For every normed vector space $X$ there is an $l \in X^*$ (the dual space of $X$) such that the $Kern(l)=\{ 0 \}$.

Is this claim true or can someone give me a counter example.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

In finite dimensions, consider the rank-nullity theorem, and note that the image space is a subspace of the codomain (so its dimension can be no higher than that of the codomain). In infinite dimensions, think of a finite dimensional subspace.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the case $X=\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: The point being, much as in the other Answer, that a linear function on a two-dimensional space will always have a nontrivial kernel.